# Problems with web sockets secure connection using jetty webserver

Tags: java, sockets, ssl, jetty

I have been having problems with getting my websocket secure (wss://) connection to work.

I recently had to switch servers and got a new SSL certificate, on my previous server wss:// connection use to work fine. On new server I generated a new keystore using instruction provided by the CA, I gave the keystore the same name and password as it had on previous server as well I placed the keystore in the same directory which the code refers to. I did all that so I don't have to change the code.

I am using the exact same .JAR file from previous server, now every time I run my application i get following error message in the console

> WebSocket connection to 'wss://example.com:8080/' failed: Error in
>   connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Websockets work fine when I turn off SSL and run it on the same port, I also made sure keystore was created properly and it was. I can't figure out what may the problem be, I would really appreciate help and guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a network issue rather than a jetty/SSL issue.  Is port 8080 open?  Try to run the command "telnet hostname 8080".  If you get a connection refused error then the port is not open.

Comment: Thanks John for your respond, I ran the telnet command I got this `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused` But what I am having hard time understanding is that the same port works without SSL. Is there some other configuration that I might have to do to for this port to work with SSL?

Comment: Above response was when I ran `telnet localhost 8080` but when i ran `telnet ipaddress 8080` i got this `telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out`

Comment: So it works without SSL?  What were the exact commands you used to create the keystore file?  I had a problem because I did not add my root cert to the list of trusted certs:
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias ALIAS -file ROOT_CERT.cer -keystore KEYSTORE.jks

Comment: I used the instruction provided by Global Sign CA and I added root Cert then intermediate cert and finally the domain cert. And I got the intended reply. Command I used to import certs was exact same as your example above.

Comment: I found the following with a quick search.  It may help.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829265/jetty-ssl-port-not-open-for-secure-jsr-356-websockets

Comment: Thanks John for the help, really appreciate it. that solution ended up fixing the problem for me.