# Jetty ssl websocket server not response

Tags: ssl, websocket, jetty

I'm trying to copy [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829265/jetty-ssl-port-not-open-for-secure-jsr-356-websockets) to reproduce the behavior. I' m using Jetty Websocket 9.2.12.v20150709. i have everything like Joakim, with the same keystore, and i get this message on start:

```
2015-07-30 14:59:32.662:INFO::main: Logging initialized @527ms
2015-07-30 14:59:33.051:INFO:oejs.Server:main: jetty-9.2.12.v20150709
2015-07-30 14:59:38.742:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:main: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@41a881cc{/,null,AVAILABLE}
2015-07-30 14:59:38.822:INFO:oejs.ServerConnector:main: Started ServerConnector@6b611e0{SSL-http/1.1}{0.0.0.0:9443}
2015-07-30 14:59:38.823:INFO:oejs.Server:main: Started @6704ms
```

Looks ok but nothing happens when call using TLS in https://www.websocket.org/echo.html, i tried with http and https url, but the server not receive nothing. I have checked that the port is open etc.... Some help with that?? Any idea?? Thanks!!

Comment: Read the tag descriptions before adding them randomly!

Comment: Sorry Olaf, but i don't understand your post. My problem is about ssl in websocket and i'm using Jetty for that. Why do you think my tags are random? I'm new asking in stackoverflow and i would like to do it well. Thanks.

Comment: That's why I told you to read the tag descriptions. Check which tag I deleted and the find out what it actually is for and you will agree that it does absolutely not belong here. Btw: you should post a [mcve]. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll have in mind for future.